# Is there a command to see all of a user's settings similar to the information displayed in the GUI?

Tags: command-line, user-management

I'm kinda a newbie to ubuntu (only been using it for about 6 months) and I love it! I have been trying to get used to the terminal interface and I use it for a lot of things relating to securing my computer (firewalls, and stuff like that) and so as I try and work on improving my terminal skills I have also been trying to move away from the GUIs. I want to know if there is a command were I can get all the information listed in the User Accounts GUI (for example account type, password options, automatic login etc) in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out information about users is through `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files.

For instance `awk -F : '!/nobody/ && $3>1000 {print $1}'` will tell you all the human users on the system and `cat /etc/group |grep sudo`  will tell you who has sudo privilleges

Automatic login is generally configured in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

There is also `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` folder where you can find some minor information on users who use graphical login. For instance, here is mine

```
[com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService]
PlayerName=''
Timestamp=0
Title=''
Artist=''
Album=''
ArtUrl=''
PlayerIcon=<('themed', <['application-default-icon', 'application-default', 'application']>)>

[User]
Language=en_US
FormatsLocale=en_US.UTF-8
XSession=gnome
Background=/usr/share/backgrounds/LOGIN-WARNING.png
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/penguin.jpg
SystemAccount=false

[InputSource0]
xkb=us

[InputSource1]
xkb=ru

[InputSource2]
ibus=sunpinyin

[InputSource3]
ibus=libpinyin
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also file [/etc/shadow](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/).
To list the currently logged-on users, type `who`.
To identify the current user, type `whoami`.